# Order of libraries and source files from makefile

Tags: gcc, makefile

I should start by saying I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to gcc and makefiles.

On an Ubuntu machine that I've recently started using, I find that when running gcc, the order in which I put the source files and the libraries/headers makes a difference.  On another machine I could do:

```
gcc -I../include -L../lib myProgram.c -o myProgram
```

But on the new machine, this will not link the libraries, and I must do:

```
gcc myProgram.c -o myProgram -I../include -L../lib
```

Now, I have the following makefile:

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
CC = gcc -O3

CFLAGS = -I../include
LDFLAGS = -L../lib

PROGS = myProgram

all: $(PROGS)

$(all): $(PROGS).o
        $(CC) -o $@ $@.o $(LIBS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
        rm -f $@.o

clean:
        rm -f *.o $(PROGS)
```

But when I do "make", the actual gcc command that it runs has the libraries and source files in the wrong order.  My question is: what do I need to do in the makefile to force the "-L../libs" option to come after the source files, so that the libraries will link properly?

I've also tried including the "-Wl,--no-as-needed" option, as I thought that an --as-needed flag might be the reason that the order matters in the first place, but this didn't appear to change anything (i.e. it still fails to link the libraries unless "-L../libs" comes after the source files).

Comment: Do you want `-L../libs` to come before the *source files* ? or is it the *object files*?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is that I want `-L../libs` to come after both the source file and the object file.

Comment: That second rule doesn't look right. Instead of `$(all): $(PROGS).o`, try `myProgram: myProgram.o` (we can worry generality once we have it working).

Comment: Aha!  That worked, though I don't think I understand why.  The `$(all): $(PROGS).o` worked when I had compiled this previously on a different machine.  Is there another way I should generalize that (there are some makefiles where I want to compile multiple object files)?

Comment: There are too many mistakes and misconceptions in evidence here to take on reasonably.
SO questions can't substitute for due diligence in studying the tools you
are trying to use. Resources: [Introductory tutorial on GCC & Make](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html).
[The GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html). [The GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/)

Comment: Duly noted, and I apologize for my ignorance.  On the other hand, work requirements do not always wait upon due diligence.  I have a bunch of programs I need to compile, and I'd like to know how to modify the makefiles following the template above so that they will compile.

Comment: I've posted an Answer below. I don't know why your makefile worked on another machine; it could have been a different default compiler, a different version of Make, or any of several other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that you thought you were using that rule, but you weren't. You never defined a variable named `all`, so the target of the second rule actually expanded to *nothing*. When you commanded Make to build `myProgram`, Make found no suitable rule in this makefile. Make has a toolbox of [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules) it can fall back on in such cases; it wanted to build `myProgram`, it saw a file named `myProgram.c`, and one of its rules looks something like this:

```
%: %.c
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

There you have it, linker flags before sources.

You can write your own pattern rule which Make will use instead:

```
%: %.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

(Note that this builds `myProgram` from `myProgram.o`, and lets Make figure out how to build `myProgram.o`.)

If your executable is to be built from several object files, add a rule like this:

```
myProgram: other.o yetAnother.o
```

If you like you can have one more rule (the first) to tell Make what you want built:

```
all: myProgram myOtherProgram friendsProgram
```

(A final note: we've all had tight work deadlines. Asking for help once can be faster than learning the tools, but learning the tools is faster than asking for help N times. Determining the value of N is up to you.)

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate the explanation.  This code, including the makefiles, is stuff I've inherited from someone else, and it didn't occur to me that there might be errors in his makefiles (I just assumed that some syntax I didn't understand was accounting for `all`).  I realize I should learn the tools, but in this instance I was desperate for a quick solution.  Thanks for providing one.

Comment: @StevenLinden: It didn't occur to you that code you inherited might contain blatant errors? Ah, youth...